# Выскакивает ошибка при команде git commit. Error in /usr/share/nano/git.nanorc

Tags: git

```
$ git commit
Error in /usr/share/nano/git.nanorc on line 1: Regex strings must begin and end with a " character
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 2: Command "
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 10: Command "
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 15: Command "
Error in /usr/share/nano/git.nanorc on line 19: Regex strings must begin and end with a " character
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 20: Command "
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 23: Command "
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 26: Command "
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 33: Command "
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 36: Command "
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 42: Command "
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 44: Command "
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 47: Command "
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 50: Command "
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 51: Command "
Error in /usr/share/nano/git.nanorc on line 53: Regex strings must begin and end with a " character
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 54: Command "
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 57: Command "
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 60: Command "
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 74: Command "
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 77: Command "
" not understoodare/nano/git.nanorc on line 80: Command "
[master c7b4569] Added h1 tag
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Откройте Git Bash, используя “Run as Administrator” в стартовом меню Windows и введите в терминал:

```
dos2unix /usr/share/nano/git.nanorc
```

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, что ошибка где-то в файле конфигурации nano для гита и он не может его открыть. Попробуйте сделать коммит сразу с коммит сообщением

```
git commit -m "Some message"
```

Если это поможет, то попробуйте настроить другой дефолтный редактор для гита, либо коммитить командой сразу с сообщением.